# Android canvas.save() and canvas.restore() make my app crash

Tags: java, android, canvas, view

I try to just display a Canvas inside a View like that :

```
protected void onPostExecute(Canvas canvas){
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        rect.set(0,0,nbColumns*65,nbLines*20);

        View v = activity.findViewById(R.id.viewOfPDF);

        int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(rect.width(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(rect.height(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        v.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

        v.layout(0, 0, rect.width(), rect.height());
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(rect.left, rect.top);
        v.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
```

But my app make an error when i run my activity. It's not an Exception :

`A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 25473 (iondestagiaires), pid 25473 (iondestagiaires)`

I do `save()` and `restore()` just this time.

My view is just a simple View.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

click on Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Deployment -> Instant Run.

Then deselect the "Enable Instant Run" checkbox at the top.

Comment: I don't have Instant run